# Is it possible to change the geometry of the appbar commands in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to customize the app bar command buttons and wondering if we can make them squares instead of circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. changing the border-radius will change the circles to squares.

```
border-radius: 0%;
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too difficult in XAML, at least (you didn't specify if it was XAML or HTML that your are using).  There is a style for the appbar button called, appropriately enough, "AppBarButtonStyle" from which all the dutton a are derived.  Without having a machine in front of me on which to check, you should be able to edit that style to get square buttons.  I imagine the CSS of an HTML app would also have something similar.

Be aware though that your users may have come to expect round buttons rather than square ones. It isn't a huge usability issue, but there may be a moment of confusion there.

Comment: I'm not an HTML guy, but if I have chance later i will take a look.  A good start point would be to do a global search of your solution for "AppBarButtonStyle" to see if it is there.